# High CPU Usage after sometime

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, c++11, mqtt

I have the following code which runs as service in linux based device.

1. It has one mqtt call back which receives the message whenever some
   one publish it on the subscribed topic.
2. One thread is to process the incoming messages on the queue. Once they processed the result message will be pushed to out_message queue.
3. One more thread is to process the outgoing message queue.
4. I have used the condition_variable to for resource sharing between the threads.

Problem is after some time ( on random time ) the cpu utilization of this application reaches to 100 %. Any issues in the given code to correct my process. Please help me !! Thank you very much in advance.

```
void pushMessage(std::string rData) {
    in_mutex.lock();
    in_queue.push(rData);
    in_mutex.unlock();
    in_cv.notify_all();
}

void pushOutGoingMessage(Json::Value data) {
    out_mutex.lock();
    out_queue.push(data);
    out_mutex.unlock();
    out_cv.notify_all();
}
void processOutGoingMessages() {
    while (true) {
        Json::Value data;
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(out_mutex);
            while (out_queue.empty()) {
                out_cv.wait(lock);
            }
            data = out_queue.front();
            out_queue.pop();
            lock.unlock();
        }
        if (!data.isNull()) {
            parseOutGoingMessages(data);
        }
    }
}

void processMessage() {
    while (true) {
        std::string data = "NO_DATA";
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(in_mutex, std::try_to_lock);
            if (!lock.owns_lock()) {

            } else {
                while (in_queue.empty()) {
                    in_cv.wait(lock);
                }
                data = in_queue.front();
                in_queue.pop();
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }
        if (data.compare("NO_DATA") != 0) {
            parseMessage(data);
        }
    }
}

void parseOutGoingMessages(Json::Value rJsonMessage) {
    // mqtt client send method
    mqtt_client.push_message(rJsonMessage.toStyledString(),
            rJsonMessage["destination"].asString());
}

void parseMessage(std::string rMessage) {
    try {
        debug(rMessage);
        // application logic
    } catch (std::exception &e) {
        debug("ERRO HANDLED IN PARSING ::" + std::string(e.what()));
    }
}

void connectMQTT() {
    // connection params
}

void OnConnectionLost(void *context, char *cause) {
    // retry logic
    connectMQTT();
}

void delivered(void *context, MQTTClient_deliveryToken dt) {

}
int OnMessageArrived(void *context, char *topicName, int topicLen,
        MQTTClient_message *message) {
    if (!message->retained) {
        std::string msg((char *) message->payload, message->payloadlen);
        pushMessage(msg);
    }
    MQTTClient_freeMessage(&message);
    MQTTClient_free(topicName);
    return 1;
}
void send(Json::Value rData,std::string rDestination) {
    Json::Value jsonNotification;
    jsonNotification["destination"] = rDestination;
    jsonNotification["data"] = rData;
    pushOutGoingMessage(jsonNotification);
}
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    connectMQTT();
    std::thread procInMessage(processMessage);
    std::thread procOutMessage(processOutGoingMessages);
    procInMessage.join();
    procOutMessage.join();
}
```

Comment: Have you used the debugger to see what code is being executed during this period?

Comment: when I start the application in debug mode I haven't find any high cpu usage. But, when I run this as daemon service in the system I found the high cpu usage

Comment: all your loops are without sleep of any sort.

Comment: There are two conditional_variables .. two loops will wait for the conditional variables..

Comment: Add some debug cout or wait until the situation occurs and then attached the debugger to view the stack.   This line seems possible   if (!lock.owns_lock()) {}  if the lock cannot be acquired then it will run hot.  Maybe an exception in pushMessage leaves the lock stuck?

Comment: You have a few bits of iffy code here any of which may be causing this. Firstly you have a hot loop when you try the `try_to_lock`. This will consume a bunch of CPU which may cause insufficient processing of other parts. Just remove that parameter. Secondly, you use manually lock/unlock in a bunch of places - this means if an exception is thrown for whatever reason you'll leave that locked permanently locked. Use a `stack_guard` or `unique_lock` always. Lastly you should use the predicate version of `condition_variable::wait` which would mean you don't need those "while-not-empty" loops.

Comment: But as @LightnessRacesinOrbit says you should just debug it. I'm no linux expert but surely you can debug demons whilst they're running?

Comment: You can attach your debugger to a running process. You don't run a program in debug mode, you build it in debug mode. And, yeah, failing all else, log to a file? Old school!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @MatthewFisher and @Mike Vine. I just modifiy the push methods on the for both queues.

```
void pushMessage(std::string rData) {
//  in_mutex.lock();
//  in_queue.push(rData);
//  in_mutex.unlock();
//  in_cv.notify_all();
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(in_mutex);
    in_queue.push(rData);
    lock.unlock();
    in_cv.notify_all();
}

void pushOutGoingMessage(Json::Value data) {
//  out_mutex.lock();
//  out_queue.push(data);
//  out_mutex.unlock();
//  out_cv.notify_all();
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(out_mutex);
    out_queue.push(data);
    lock.unlock();
    out_cv.notify_all();
}
```

And the problem was solved I guess. It was purley due to (!lock.owns_lock()) {} in push method for both the queues.